# Reference spring-boot assembled jar in gradle ssh plugin

Tags: gradle, ssh, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I would like to create a custom task in gradle, that will upload assembled jar to a remote server.

My best working result is

```
doLast {
    ssh.run {
        def jarFile = "${jar.baseName}-${version}.jar"
        session(remotes.role('qa')) {
            put from: file("build/libs/${jarFile}"), into: "/home/${user}"
            execute("sudo cp ${jarFile} /usr/share/feedserver/", pty: true)
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However this uses jar.baseName property, which is deprecated and gives a warning:

> The baseName property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the archiveBaseName property instead.

What would be the right way replacing it ?

Suggested archiveBaseName does not work, E.g.

```
task updateOnQA(dependsOn: bootJar) {
    doLast {
        def jarFile = "${jar.archiveBaseName}-${version}.jar"
        print "${jarFile}";
    }
}
```

Outputs

> task ':myproject:jar' property 'archiveBaseName'-1.0.12.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecated `baseName` property returns a `String`, whereas the new `archiveBaseName` returns a `Provider<String>`. To get the actual value from the provider, you have to call `.get()`. The same goes for the `version` property, which has been replaced by the provider called `archiveVersion`.

If you want to use those new properties, you could update your task to this:

```
task updateOnQA(dependsOn: bootJar) {
    doLast {
        def jarFile = "${jar.archiveBaseName.get()}-${archiveVersion.get()}.jar"
        print "${jarFile}"
    }
}
```

But if you are looking for the actual path of the jar file, you could use:

```
put from: jar.archiveFile.get().getAsFile(), into: "/home/${user}"
```

Here, the first `.get()` call returns a `RegularFile` from the provider, and the `.getAsFile()` call converts it to a normal `File`.